# how to open the json inside dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that come from SharePoint (Microsoft), and it has a lot of jsons inside the cells with the metadata. i usually dont work with json, so im struggling with it.

```
# df sample

+-------------+----------+
| Id          | Event    |
+-------------+----------+
| 105         | x        |
+-------------+----------+
```

```
x = {"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"Digital Training"}
```

How i assign just the value "Digital Training" to the cell, for example? remembering that this is ocurring for a lot of columns, and i need to solve it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the event column consists of `dict`-object:

```
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Event']['Value'], 1)
```

If the event column has string objects:

```
import json
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x['Event'])['Value'], 1)
```

Both result in

```
    Id  Event                                               Value
0   x   {"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.Sh...   Digital Training
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I would like a solution that does that for every necessary collumn, changing the 'Value'. But i think that this is not that simple, so im gonna use your solution for sure!

Comment: that is possible aswell. Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html. Get back on me if it doesn't work. I can update the answer ;)